# can not get CISourceOverCompositing to work

Tags: ios, avfoundation, cifilter

Im using CISourceOverCompositing to merge images and export as CVPixelBuffer.Everything works fine when image count down below 41. But when it hit 42 or greater, the result become all black scean. heres my processing code:

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBufferRefWithMergingStillMaterials:(NSArray *)materials withBackgroundSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer {
// 基于gpu合并所有图层

CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

CIImage *backgroundImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];

static int i = 0;
i=0;
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"];
// 合并静态素材到一个CIImage
for (id<MicroVideoStillMaterial> stillMaterial in materials) {

    CIImage *foregroundImage = [stillMaterial image];


    [filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:backgroundImage forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
    [filter setValue:foregroundImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    backgroundImage = filter.outputImage;
    i++;
}

NSLog(@"iiiiiiiiiii  %d", i);

EAGLContext *glContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:glContext];

CFDictionaryRef empty = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, // EMPTY IOSURFACE DICT
                                           NULL,
                                           NULL,
                                           0,
                                           &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                           &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFMutableDictionaryRef attributes = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                              1,
                                                              &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                                              &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFDictionarySetValue(attributes,kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey,empty);

CVPixelBufferRef outputPixelBuffer = NULL;

CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault, width, height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, attributes, &outputPixelBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(outputPixelBuffer, 0);
[context render:backgroundImage toCVPixelBuffer:outputPixelBuffer];

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(outputPixelBuffer, 0);

return outputPixelBuffer;
}
```

and this piece of code run in a background thread.anyone has any idea please help.thanks